# iOS Google Silent Sign In provides a (valid) token with missing profile info

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-signin, google-identity

I've integrated Google SignIn SDK (v4.0.1) to my iOS app.
The normal authentication process is working fine via:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

The retrieved idToken is valid and includes both email and the user's basic info:
given_name
family_name
picture

- Google provide this URL for reviewing token data:
  https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=

Problem is, after relaunching the app, I perform silent login on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` like so:

```
if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
}
```

The delegate function `sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!)` is being called. And the authentication seem to have completed successfully. However, the idToken retrieved (from user.authentication.idToken) is missing the info of the "profile" scope. Only email field is provided.

Sending this idToken to our backend server results in a valid login but with missing info populated into our db. frustrating.

It feels like `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()` does not respect `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().shouldFetchBasicProfile` even if set true beforehand.

Attempt to refresh the token at this stage by running `user.authentication.refreshTokens:handler` produces a new token, again, with missing profile scope.

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround for this?

Comment: @CodeCommander User details are fetched during authentication on our backend server. specifically using Python module called oauth2client.client -> function verify_id_token