# Why does Google Sign-In on iOS result in incomplete data on the backend server intermittently?

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin, scopes

I am developing a Swift 4 app and want to include Google Sign in. I have done the following already ...

In AppDelegate `viewDidLoad`

```
import GoogleSignIn
```

then in the main body

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    ...

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()!.options.clientID // Note this key is the same as extracted from GoogleService-Info.plist
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    ...
}


// Handle requested external URLs
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: [:])
}


func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {

    if let error = error {
        // .. handle error
    }

    let email = user.profile.email

    // Here I always have seem to have access to the givenName and firstName
    Log.trace("First name: " + user.profile.givenName)
    Log.trace("Lastst name: " + user.profile.familyName)

    let googleToken  = user.authentication.idToken

    // Send googleToken/email to backend server ...

}
```

then in the `touchUpInside` when clicking a sign-in button it calls the following setup ...

```
...

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes! = ["profile", "email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"]
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()

...
```

However the back-end server logs show that sometimes, not always, the 'given_name' is not available to the server when using the token.

This sign-in with the same scopes work fine for the Android app using the Google Sign-in library. The information we need on the back-end server is

- Given name
- Family name
- Email
- Sub (Google's name for userID?)

EDIT

It seems to be related to [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189966/ios-google-silent-sign-in-provides-a-valid-token-with-missing-profile-info). Specifically, when I am sent off to explicitly choose an account to sign-in with the token comes back with the Given Name and Family Name but when it signs in in the background the ID toke is missing the basic profile info.

Comment: What is on your backend? Firebase?

Comment: @Brendan did u check that strings your sending to the server is empty for given name.It may be the possibility it sometimes may be empty.

Comment: We have our own backend but we have Firebase installed in the app for use with cloud messaging and crash reports

Comment: have you found the answer?